# How to show filtered items only after adding to cart on home page in django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, filter, e-commerce, cart

i am practicing django by making an ecommerce app. I also share the video so that you can also check the problem.
https://youtu.be/crYlZ7Bo8y4

Application is working perfectly but when i filter the product according to selected category and press **add to cart** button then it will show all products of all categories instead of showing selected products under that category.

Can you please help me out in this.

**index.html page:**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% load cart %}
{% load custom_filter %}
<!-- body -->
<div class="container-fluid mt-3">
    <div class="row">


        <!-- filter -->

        <div class="col-lg-3 mx-auto">
            <div class="list-group">

                <a href="/" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">All Products</a>

                {% for category in categories %}
                <a href="/?category={{category.id}}"
                    class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">{{category.name}}</a>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- all products -->
        <div id='products' class="col-lg-9 mx-auto">
            <div class="row mx-auto">
                {% for product in products %}
                <div class="card mx-auto mb-3" id={{product.id}} style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{product.image.url}}" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-title">{{product.name}}</p>
                        <p class="card-text"><b>{{product.price|currency}}</b></p>
                        <!-- {{product | is_in_cart:request.session.cart }} -->
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-footer p-0 no-gutters">

                        {% if product|is_in_cart:request.session.cart %}
                        <div class="row no-gutters">
                            <form action="/#{{product.id}}" class="col-2 " method="post">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <input hidden type="text" name='product' value='{{product.id}}'>
                                <input hidden type="text" name='remove' value='True'>
                                <input type="submit" value=" - " class="btn btn-block btn-light border-right">
                            </form>
                            <div class="text-center col">{{product|cart_quantity:request.session.cart}} in Cart</div>
                            <form action="/#{{product.id}}" class="col-2 " method="post">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <input hidden type="text" name='product' value='{{product.id}}'>
                                <input type="submit" value=" + " class="btn btn-block btn-light border-left">
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        {% else %}
                        <form action="/#{{product.id}}" method="POST" class="btn-block">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <input hidden type="text" name='product' value='{{product.id}}'>
                            <input type="submit" class="float-right btn btn-light  form-control"
                                value="Add To Cart">
                        </form>
                        {% endif %}

                    </div>

                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



{% endblock %}
```

**index.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render , redirect , HttpResponseRedirect
from user.models.product import Product
from user.models.category import Category
from django.views import View


# Create your views here.
class Index(View):

    def post(self , request):
        product = request.POST.get('product')
        remove = request.POST.get('remove')
        cart = request.session.get('cart')
        if cart:
            quantity = cart.get(product)
            if quantity:
                if remove:
                    if quantity<=1:
                        cart.pop(product)
                    else:
                        cart[product]  = quantity-1
                else:
                    cart[product]  = quantity+1

            else:
                cart[product] = 1
        else:
            cart = {}
            cart[product] = 1

        request.session['cart'] = cart
        print('cart', request.session['cart'])
        return redirect('user:homepage')



    def get(self , request):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(f'/store{request.get_full_path()[1:]}')

def store(request):
    cart = request.session.get('cart')
    if not cart:
        request.session['cart'] = {}
    products = None
    categories = Category.get_all_categories()
    categoryID = request.GET.get('category')
    if categoryID:
        products = Product.get_all_products_by_categoryid(categoryID)
    else:
        products = Product.get_all_products();

    data = {}
    data['products'] = products
    data['categories'] = categories

    print('you are : ', request.session.get('email'))
    return render(request, 'index.html', data)
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views.index import Index,store
from .views.signup import Signup
from .views.login import Login,logout

app_name = 'user'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', Index.as_view(), name='homepage'),
    path('store', store, name='store'),
    path('signup', Signup.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('login', Login.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout', logout, name='logout'),
]
```

**cart.py template tag:**

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='is_in_cart')
def is_in_cart(product  , cart):
    keys = cart.keys()
    for id in keys:
        if int(id) == product.id:
            return True
    return False;


@register.filter(name='cart_quantity')
def cart_quantity(product  , cart):
    keys = cart.keys()
    for id in keys:
        if int(id) == product.id:
            return cart.get(id)
    return 0;


@register.filter(name='price_total')
def price_total(product  , cart):
    return product.price * cart_quantity(product , cart)


@register.filter(name='total_cart_price')
def total_cart_price(products , cart):
    sum = 0 ;
    for p in products:
        sum += price_total(p , cart)

    return sum
```

**Custom_filter.py template tag:**

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='currency')
def currency(number):
    return "₹ "+str(number)

@register.filter(name='multiply')
def multiply(number , number1):
    return number * number1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
referer = request.META['HTTP_REFERER']
return redirect(referer)
```

You can get the referring page of request instead of redirecting a constant link.You can  also check [META](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META)